# FBProfilePictureView doesnt load image until UICollectionView scrolling stops

Tags: facebook, sdk, uicollectionview

I am using Facebook SDK in xcode. I have a UICollectionView.  When a new UICollectionViewCell appears I set the FBProfilePictureView = nil so that previous cell images are removed.

However, the new facebook profile pictures wont appear until I stop the UICollectionView scrolling?  So if I keep scrolling the images never appear and then the instant I stop scrolling (e.g. by tapping on the collection view) the image appears.

Has anyone else come across this strange behaviour and knows of a way to resolve it?

Cheers, Charlie

Comment: Being down voted but have no idea why.  Please could down votes provide a comment so I can update this question appropriately? Many thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue (with both UITableViews and UICollectionViews - hopefully it will be fixed soon:

Here are details of the bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/487007427983915/